# How do I recive the response from API in PHP CRUL and initializes it in a variable?

Tags: php, curl

```
    $url="https://api.****.com/**/****/";
$ch=curl_init($url);
$resonse=curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST=>"POST",
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>
'fields name,****,*****, ****; search "*****";',


CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=>array(
"Client-ID:*********",
"Authorization:**** *****",
"Accept:application/json"

)

));
$res=curl_exec($ch);
```

Hello, I'm using this code to get data from the API. The data is simply printed on the screen. How do I put the data I get back into variable to use? Thanks!

Comment: 1) What do you mean by "array I get back"? An API can't return an array, so there must be a piece of code that decodes it into an array once received. 2) Nothing in the code you presented does any printing. Altogether, it seems you omitted some relevant code. Can you please elaborate on your case?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should not be printing anything (it doesn't when I run it), but it does save the contents it gets from the endpoint as a string. Most APIs use JSON nowadays, and since you are specifying it in your header I assume yours does too. You can use `json_decode()` to turn that into a python array/object:

```php
$res = json_decode( curl_exec($ch) );
```